# Ruby 'uninitialized constant' error even with gem required

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

I'm trying to use the Ankusa (https://github.com/livingsocial/ankusa) gem in a ruby project I'm working on.

I'm running the code below with the ankusa gem installed but I still get an error:
    uninitialized constant Ankusa::MemoryStorage (NameError)

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'ankusa'
require 'ankusa/hbase_storage'

storage = Ankusa::MemoryStorage.new
c = Ankusa::NaiveBayesClassifier.new storage

c.train :spam, "This is some spammy text"
c.train :good, "This is not the bad stuff"

puts c.classify "This is some spammy text"

puts c.classifications "This is some spammy text"

puts c.log_likelihoods "This is some spammy text"

puts c.classnames
storage.close
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a look at `ankusa.rb` within the gem folder. It only requires the following:

```
require 'ankusa/version'
require 'ankusa/extensions'
require 'ankusa/classifier'
require 'ankusa/naive_bayes'
require 'ankusa/kl_divergence'
require 'ankusa/hasher'
```

so, you might need to require it explicitly

```
require 'ankusa/memory_storage'
```

Comment: Thanks that works. I needed 'ankusa' and  'ankusa/memory_storage'